# How to find a basis and dimension of two subspaces together with their intersection space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

> Given a vector $[a,b,c,d]^T$ ,find a basis for the subspace $S$ of $\Bbb{R}^4$ such that $a+c+d = 0$
> and for the subspace $T$ such that $a+b = 0$ and $c = 2d$.
>
> What is the dimension of the intersection $S∩T$?

---

My approach, it is known that to form a basis the vectors must be linearly independent, and this should be a spanning set. 
Basis for subspace $S$,

$\begin{align}&\{(a,b,c,d)| a+c+d=0\}\\&=\{(a,b,-a-d,d) | a+c+d=0\}\\&=\{a(1,0,-1,0)\} +\{b(0,1,0,0)\}+\{d(0,0,-1,1)\}\end{align}$

Hence $\dim = 3$ and basis is $\{(1,0,-1,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,-1,1)\}$

Basis for subspace $T$,

$\begin{align}&\{(a,b,c,d): a+b=0 \text{ and } c= 2d\}\\&=\{(a,-a,2d,d)\}
\\&=\{a(1,-1,0,0) + d(0,0,2,1)\}\end{align}$

$\dim T= 2$  and  basis is $\{(1,-1,0,0),(0,0,2,1)\}$.

Hence
$\dim(S∩T)= 1 $

I'd appreciate corrections or if there is a more technical way to approach this. I am little confused on the transpose part as well, I want to understand the significance of this representation. Might be it wanted to reflect that those are column vectors. I need validation on the answer. thanks!

Note: Here $[a, b, c, d]^T$ means the column vector $\{\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}\}$

Comment: "*i'm a little confused on the transpose part as well*"  Some people strongly prefer writing column vectors instead of row vectors.  There is no significance here, just personal preference of the question author.  "*dim = 4 (of S)*" This is wrong.  The dimension of $\Bbb R^4$ is $4$.  Your set $S$ is smaller than $\Bbb R^4$ and so must have dimension smaller than $4$.  Try again.

Comment: You did well with looking at $T$, having reused your $a$'s and $d$'s where appropriate to.  Why did you not do that for $S$?  Recall that $a+c+d=0$.  For the final conclusion "*$S\cap T = 2$*" How did you come to that conclusion?  Is $S\cap T$ really all of $T$?  Or are there elements in $T$ which are not in $S\cap T$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out on this, really appreciate, I have edited this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S=\textrm{null}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{align}\mathcal{B}_S&=\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},  
\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\}\end{align}$

$\dim S=3$

---

$T=\textrm{null}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathcal{B}_T=\{\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$

$\dim T=2$

---

$S\cap T=\textrm{null}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{align}\textrm{rref}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-2\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&3\\0&1&0&-3\\0&0&1&-2\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$

$\mathcal{B}_{S\cap T}=\{\begin{pmatrix}-3\\3\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$

$\dim(S\cap T) =1$